# Regex between two nth position characters

Tags: regex

I'm trying to fetch some data depending from a text string that lies between two characters (_) but could be a word in a nth position.

Currently I have the following

```
!((?:.*?(_)){2})_(.+?)$
```

working on the following data

```
D20_Mbps_U10_Mbps_TC4_P
```

where I would expect to get

```
U10
```

but get nothing as the first part captures

```
D20_Mbps_
```

and thus leaves nothing for the second part to capture

I've tried

```
_\s*(.*?)(?=\s*_)
```

But this only gives me the first occurance where I need it to be nth position. Where I can supply n at runtime.

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You can try a negated character class: [`^(?:[^_]*_){2}([^_]*)_(.+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/sI9aP9/2). Group 1 will contain `U10`. Group 2 will contain the ending part. What is the programming language BTW?

Comment: I wonder if my comment above works for you, is it? Your questions sounds a bit unclear: are you just trying to get the `U10`? Then I guess, `^(?:[^_]*_){2}([^_]*)` is enough. Again, what is your regex flavor?

Comment: I'm using Perl. I know that I could use string manipulation, but this needs to be code independent as this regex is passed with the data into the perl script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me try answering this in detail.

When you want to match some Nth occurrence of a substring within a delimited string, you should really think of some `String.Split` function. In your case, splitting with `_` and getting the values you need is a trivial task.

Now, when you cannot use a programming means to extract that value, you can only do this with a *limiting quantifier*, grouping and capturing (in Java and .NET, it is possible to achieve the same even without capturing).

So, the main idea is to match 0 or more characters other than your delimiter and then match the delimiters itself, and then *repeat the same* N-1 times. Then, just match the delimiter again and capture following non-delimiter characters.

```
^(?:[^_]*_){2}([^_]*)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sI9aP9/2). Group 1 will contain `U10`.

Or [another variation](https://regex101.com/r/sI9aP9/2):

```
^(?:[^_]*_){2}([^_]*)_(.+)$
```

This will capture the 3rd `_`-delimited element into Group 1. Group 2 in this case is the 4th+ elements, the rest of the string up to the end.

Note that in some regex flavors `{` and `(` must be escaped (vim, sed with non-EGREP versions, etc.).

Comment: Thanks. That works like a charm. When I just change the number I get that column. For some reason I just could not find an answer on the net and get it working.